# Uninstall Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: uninstall

I downloaded Ubuntu 13.10 so that I could remove the administrator password on my laptop since I forgot it.I was in "try Ubuntu" mode while trying to recover/reset the password, but I kept running into issues.

I hit "Install" the next time, went through the steps up to the part where it didn't give me an option to install alongside Windows Vista. I just installed it and it brought me to the "Disk/Partition" part of the install. I used my hard-drive (/dev/sda3). Since then, I have not been able to use Windows Vista. Please advise how to uninstall Ubuntu 13.10 and revert the changes. Thanks!I would like to remove Ubuntu 13.10 from my windows partition /dev/sda3. How would I do this? Will it revert the partition back to Windows Vista? Please advise. Thanks!

UPDATE:

Instead of trying to uninstall Ubuntu 13.10 I just decided to complete the following steps to get Windows Vista back on the correct partition.

1. Logged into Ubuntu 13.10 and changed drives/partitions to NFTS in "Disk"
2. download Wintoflash [here]
3. Followed the instructions [here]

After installing Windows Vista via USB my operating system was back up and running!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install it on the same partiton? If so, and without wubi, you lost windows... If you didn't go to terminal (windows key, type "terminal") and type in "sudo update-grub" then type in your password. This would add windows to the list you'll see when you power up. Select from the list "windows (loader)" if it exsist.

Comment: Yes, I installed it on the same partition I think. I did as you asked and this is what came up. 

Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-19-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.11.0-12-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-12-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done

Comment: I was able to transfer all files from my Vista Reinstallation DVD to a USB drive, but it says that I cannot install, needs to be formatted as NTFS. How do i do that? I have not uninstalled Ubuntu 13.10 yet. Please help!

Comment: I see you fixed it, Ubuntu can still be reinstalled with vista if you want to.